# Bundler cannot find installed gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a Gemfile with the following contents:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'knife-cloudstack', :git => 'git://github.com/CloudStack-extras/knife-cloudstack.git'
```

On doing a bundle-install, i get the following output

```
bundle install --binstubs
...
Using knife-cloudstack (0.0.13) from git://github.com/CloudStack-extras/knife-cloudstack.git (at master)
...
```

But now when i do a bundle show, bundler cannot find the knife-cloudstack gem

```
bundle show knife-cloudstack
Could not find gem 'knife-cloudstack (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine
```

I am not sure what i am missing here. Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tried the exact same thing, and seems to work fine for me. What version of ruby are you using? What's the output of "gem environment"? Does running "bundle show" show any gems? Are you running on a linux machine? if so, you might be able to find out where it writes the gems to using: "strace -f -eopen -o/tmp/strace.log bundle install"

cheers